# div animate not working jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle1.css">
  <title>hd images</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="top1">
    <div class="inside1">
      <div class="nested_inside1"> MY HAPPY PLACES </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inside2">
      <div class="nested_inside2"> CLUMSSY BEACHES
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inside3">
      <div class="nested_inside3"> REGULAR APPLES </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inside4">
      <div class="nested_inside4"> LUSTY BRUSHES </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inside5">
      <div class="nested_inside5"> ECSTATIC DIMENSIONS </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inside6">
      <div class="nested_inside6"> CURLY HILLS </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inside7">
      <div class="nested_inside7"> SHINY WATER </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inside8">
      <div class="nested_inside8"> COOL BOATS </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inside9">
      <div class="nested_inside9"> CRUNCHY CLUSHTERS </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#top1").on("hover", ".nested_inside", function() {
    $(this).animate({
      "top": "-10px"
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't work since you dont' have a class `nested_inside` but `nested_inside1`, `ensted_inside2` ... and so on... you have to remove the numbers

adapt it like this for each and every one:

```
<div class="inside7">
  <div class="nested_inside"> SHINY WATER </div>
</div>
```

and you also need to inlcude jquery in your head:

```
<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
```

adapt your code like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#top1").on("mouseover", ".nested_inside", function() {
     $(this).animate({
    "top": "-10px"
    }); 
  });
 });
```

and your CSS like this:

```
.nested_inside {
  position: relative;
}
```

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jnb7p14o/2/

Comment: actually i removed it and changed it to nested_inside but still it's not working

Comment: i have included the link 
<script src="./myquery.js"></script>
still not working

Comment: updated my answer, this should work for you. please hit upvote and check my answer if it solved your problem ;-)

Comment: actually file is not getting worked..i have tried to insert an alert between it but alert is not shown up....like this
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("hello");
.......
.....
});

i have one more javascript file attached but it;s properly working

Comment: but as you can see, my provided jsfiddle works, doesn't it? so you have to adapt your code to my suggestion.

Comment: yeah ur one gets worked byt actually the javascript file is not getting attached

Comment: well, that's another problem. could you please then checkmark my answer, if it helped you ;-) thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 <head>
 <script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle1.css">
<title>hd images</title>
</head>
```

You need to add the link to the jquery file in your `<head>` then add your jquery file after that.

Comment: i have included the link 
<script src="./myquery.js"></script>
still not working

Answer (score 0):

There are two inherent problems with this:

- The CSS - Add position: relative to `.nested_inside` to make sure the `top` property works
- The hover event has been removed from [jQuery 1.8](http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes). You'll need to replace it with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` and do the necessary animations if you're using the latest version of jQuery

I've added a fiddle based on my assumption of how it should work: 
https://jsfiddle.net/fxmtz2yn/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#top1").on("mouseover mouseleave", ".nested_inside",function(evt) {
    var $el = $(this),
        top = $el;
    switch(evt.type) {
        case "mouseover": 
            $el.animate({
                "top": "-10px"
            });
            break;
        case "mouseleave": 
           $el.animate({
               "top": "0"
           });
           break;
    }   
  });
});
```

Comment: actually file is not getting worked..i have tried to insert an alert between it but alert is not shown up....like this
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("hello");
.......
.....
});

i have one more javascript file attached but it;s properly working

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".nested_inside").hover( function(){
  $(this).animate({"top": "-10px"});
},function(){
 $(this).animate({"top":"initial"});
})
```

hover() need a callback

Comment: actually file is not getting worked..i have tried to insert an alert between it but alert is not shown up....like this
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("hello");
.......
.....
});

i have one more javascript file attached but it;s properly working